# How to read stdin from parent process?

Tags: c++, bash

I need to write program that starts bash and checks user's input. For example, if I write "io", the program must print to stdout "LOL". Unfortunately, my code doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>

int         main(int ac, char **av)
{
    ssize_t count;

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1 :
        {
            std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 0 : // child
        {
            char    curr = 0, prev = 0;

            while ((count = read(0, (void*)&curr, 1)))
            {
                if (count == -1)
                {
                    std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                    return 1;
                }
                if (prev == 'i' && curr == 'o')
                {
                    std::cout << "LOL" << std::endl;
                }
                prev = curr;
            }
            break;
        }
        default: // parent
        {
            char *const *bashArgs = {NULL};

            execvp("bash", bashArgs);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code above just infinitely reads what I'm writing on konsole and then fails with somewhat "bash:  the shit i wrote: command not found". Then inifinite reading stops and I'm in bash session. Then I just exit this session via Ctrl+D to my default bash session.

Also I tried to do this via pipe() and dup2(). The code below just starts session and does nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>

int         main(int ac, char **av)
{
    ssize_t count;
    int     fd[2];

    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1 :
        {
            std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 0 : // child
        {
            char    curr = 0, prev = 0;

            while ((count = read(fd[0], (void*)&curr, 1)))
            {
                if (count == -1)
                {
                    std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                    return 1;
                }
                if (prev == 'i' && curr == 'o')
                {
                    std::cout << "LOL" << std::endl;
                }
                prev = curr;
            }
            break;
        }
        default: // parent
        {
            char *const *bashArgs = {NULL};

            dup2(STDIN_FILENO, fd[1]);

            execvp("bash", bashArgs);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either the program gets the user's input or bash does, but not both.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to run this under `strace -f` (check the man page for other options - and probably send strace's output to a file you can tail from another terminal). It's often very informative to see exactly what is actually happening.

Comment: @stark I need to write program that starts bash and checks user's input. For example, if I write "io", the program must print to stdout "LOL".

Comment: @Useless I don't even know what I should use to get the stding from parent.

Comment: It sounds like you want your program to read from the user and then send it to bash unless it is a command that you want to intercept.

Comment: @DamirGazizov If I were you I would open bash in a child process with pipe as stdin, read characters in the parent process and pass it to the pipe as needed. This way only one process has access to the input, and you can make sure it is your program that reads it.

Comment: the header files being included are for C++, not C.  Statements like: `std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;` are only valid in C++.  Please remove the `c` tag from your question and add the `c++` tag.

Comment: @stark you said: "Either the program gets the user's input or bash does, but not both."

Why not both? And how to copy user input from bash (parent process) to children ?